# Bootstrap modal - Prevent shift AND background scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I was having trouble to prevent background shifting when bootstrap modal opened. I added the following classes to my css:

```
.modal {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

.modal-open {
 overflow: auto !important;
}
```

It worked, but now background can scroll up and down. How do I fix both problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the css like this:

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.modal {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```